# mysql 5.7 data directory has files in it

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

Following the tutorial at:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

Running docker-compose up I get:

```
Initializing database
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
[ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
[ERROR] Aborting
```

Have tried adding arguments as suggested here:
https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/186
https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69

But this doesn't seems to work:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: ["mysqld", "--ignore-db-dir=lost+found", "--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp"]
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

Is there another solution?

Comment: I had run out of space on my Harddrive for Docker containers. Using prune commands fixed it:
https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using:

```
docker volume prune
```

> Remove all unused local volumes. Unused local volumes are those which
>   are not referenced by any containers

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/